# In SQLite3, is there a way to not allow a duplicate field when another field is the same value?

Tags: sqlite, unique-constraint

This is very hard to explain which is probably why I can't find an answer. For example, I have one table of "recipe", "ingredient". Ingredients would obviously be reused for different recipes so I can't use UNIQUE, but I want the command to refuse any attempts to insert into the database of a specific recipe where the ingredient already exists in that recipe.

For example, a record: ingredient = "apple", recipe = "applePie"; don't allow the insertion of another "apple" with the field recipe = "applePie" (in my actual application, other fields besides this may exist, they may be different on both records but they both have the same ingredient and recipe, so the second attempt to insert a value should be refused unless the ingredient does not exist).

Sorry if this is incredibly basic, I thought there must be a way to natively handle this without needing my program to select and compare within the code. I don't know how well I explained everything, please let me know if you need clarity.

Thank you!

Comment: "This is very hard to explain" -- Then a [example], which is required in every question here anyway, would certainly help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, someone managed to answer it anyway though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table's `CREATE` statement define a `UNIQUE` constraint for the combination of the columns `ingredient` and `recipe`:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  recipe TEXT,
  ingredient TEXT,
  UNIQUE(recipe, ingredient)
)
```

Now, if you try to insert a row with the same `recipe` and `ingredient` as an existing row, you will get an error and the new row will not be inserted.